# Rewrite rule to change image path from image server url to my url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have images on some image server, this is a sample url:

> http://myimagehost.com/images/20161230/16/006254/thumb/1.jpg

where `006254` is the ID of image.

Now, I have a new website (e.g. http://newsite.com) and I want to link to images without the need to copy them.

What is rewrite rule to link my image myimagehost.com/images/20161230/16/006254/thumb/1.jpg from image server but to have img url looks like newsite.com/imgz/006254.jpg

i tried some rules in htaccess but get message 404 Not Found
nginx/1.11.6 (i`m a beginner with nginx)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: .htaccess is for apache. Also, check out [this link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) and nginx docs to see how to write rewrite rules. There are plenty of examples, as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i cant find answer to my question there